# C# Привязать код к кнопке вызова этого кода?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать так, что бы это действие вызывалось при нажатии на кнопку?

```
public class ScrollObjects : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5f, checkPos = 0f;
    private RectTransform rec;

    void Start()
    {
        rec = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (rec.offsetMax.x != checkPos)

        {
            rec.offsetMin += new Vector2(speed, rec.offsetMin.y);
            rec.offsetMax += new Vector2(speed, rec.offsetMax.y);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, для начала, возможно, стоит изучить документацию Button :)
Ну, а в целом есть два метода.
Первый - метод в классе делаете публичным. У самого компонента Button в инспекторе есть поле On Click - это то, что произойдет при нажатии на кнопку. Нажимаете там плюс, перетаскиваете внутрь объект, на котором висит ваш скрипт, выбираете в выпадающем списке нужный метод, вводите параметр, если требуется.
Второй - добавляете в ваш класс следующие строки:

```
    [SerializeField]
    Button _button;

    void Start()
    {
        _button.onClick.AddListener(YouMethod);
    }

    void YouMethod()
    {
        //делаете что-либо
    }
```

Теперь выбираете на сцене объект, на котором висит ваш класс и перетаскиваете в поле вашего компонента нужную кнопку.

Все вышеописанное это к тому, как сделать, чтобы что-то вызывалось при нажатии на кнопку. Отталкиваясь от этого, думаю, вы уже и сами поймёте, как запускать движение только по клику. (например, простейший вариант - завести и по клику переключать bool isMoving, а в цикле Update проверять сначала равен ли он true и только в этом случае производить манипуляции);